# Why the US zip codes which are not in use is accepting even after validating with proper regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, validation, zipcode

I'm validating US zip code values in PHP. From a form I'm getting one zip code value from the end user. If it's not a valid US zip code an error should be thrown. It throws for some values for some it's not even they are invalid US zip codes. Suppose if user enters zip code value 35302 it must throw an error since 353 is not in use. For zip codes which are currently in use and which are not in use you can refer this link 
[Wikipedia link to all available US zip code values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ZIP_code_prefixes)

Now let's come to the regex code I used for validation :

```
function zip_code($str) {    
    return (bool) preg_match("/^([0-9]{5})(-[0-9]{4})?$/i", $str);
  }
```

**Note :** Here the `$str` contains the zip code value to be validated.

Please help me in correcting the mistake that I'm making in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how will regex know `353` is not in use?

Comment: @vks:I know and understand this. But what should be the solution on this issue then. I've to show error message when user enters the invalid US zip code.

Comment: you will have to add conditions using negative lookahead.If its a long list then it would add up to a big regex.`(?!353)` something like this at the start of your regex after `^`

Comment: Appropriate that the "Hot Meta Posts" box beside this question includes "Should we add a 'Do my work form' close reason." Clearly the answer is "yes." http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason?cb=1

Comment: create a array of valid zip code prefixes and do in_array lookup. thats the simples solution imho. or if not in use zip codes are less then you can craete array of it and again do regex && !in_array lookup.

Answer (score 0):

As vks said, the regex has no idea of what kind of data you're trying to work with.

A regex is for *pattern matching*, nothing more, nothing less.

You could use a regex to extract the first three digits of the zip code and compare those against whatever data you have for zip codes.

Answer (score 0):

The USPS has an API to look up zip codes. You could call it directly instead of doing a regex (for one thing a regex doesn't guarantee that a specific code is valid, only that the prefix is valid):
https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.htm